# Access variable from other namespaces

Tags: c#, variables, namespaces

I am trying to set/read a variable in class bluRemote from another namespace/class like so:

```
namespace BluMote
{
    class bluRemote
    {
        public string cableOrSat = "CABLE";
     ........
    }
}
```

and the other cs file (which is the form):

```
namespace BluMote
{
    public partial class SettingsForm : Form
    {
        if (BluMote.bluRemote.cableOrSat == "CABLE")
        {
             BluMote.bluRemote.cableOrSat = "SAT";
        }
 .......
    }
}
```

I know i am doing it wrong but I'm more used to doing stuff like this in VB so its like night and day ha :o)

Comment: @Jeff: It's an internal class... it would work fine if it weren't for the static/instance problem. It's not an accessibility problem.

Comment: @Jon: Ah right, I was thinking it was `private` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is work with static variables so you would need to change your class to this:

```
namespace BluMote
{
    public static class bluRemote
    {
        public static string cableOrSat = "CABLE";
        ........
    }
}
```

It is better if you stay away from static classes (for the most part) and instead focus on an object oriented approach where you have an instance (object) of bluRemote.

So instead of making the bluRemote class static you keep it the same and do:

```
public partial class SettingsForm : Form
{
    private bluRemote _remote = new bluRemote();  // possibly created somewhere else

    public void SomeFunction() 
    {
        if (_remote.cableOrSat == "CABLE")
        {
             _remote.cableOrSat = "SAT";
        }
    }
    .......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access an *instance* variable - i.e. one which has a potentially different value for each object - just by *class* name. That only works for *static* variables.

You need to have an *instance* of `bluRemote`, and ask *that* for its value. However, I would strongly suggest that:

- You rename your class to follow .NET naming conventions
- You *don't* make variables public; use properties

Also note that there's only *one* namespace here - `BluMote`. Both of your classes are declared in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As you've declared the `cableOrSat` field, you'll need to set it on an instance of the `bluRemote` class, but you are trying to set it using the name of the class itself.

If you declare the `cableOrSat` field as:

`public static string cableOrSat = "CABLE";`

You will be able to access it through the class name itself.